# Burn based UI for msi installer

Tags: .net, wix, installation, burn, wix3.6

I need to create a sample by using the [Burn](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2011/10/24/WiX-v3.6-Beta-released) based UI for msi installer.
Will anyone able to guide this for me or please send an sample for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For a good demo. Download the WiX 3.6 sources at:
http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/75656#DownloadId=296223

Checkout the WiX installer itself in:
src\Setup